# Can the time reset password ever be 00000 in Pokemon GSC?

Tags: pokemon-gold-silver-crystal

In Pokémon Gold&Silver there is a time reset function that requires a password which is calculated from Trainername, Money and Trainer-ID.

Can it ever be 00000? And if so can it be this way for any Trainername+ID or just some special Trainer-IDs/names?

I looked up several sites which calculate the password, but I didn't found a site which calculates the money you need to have for a specific password.

Another password which would be desirable would be 0000X, since that way you only have to change one digit, so if 00000 is not possible maybe 0000X is?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, the password cannot be 00000. In fact, it cannot even start with more than two "0" digits.

According to [this guide](https://gamefaqs.gamespot.com/gbc/198308-pokemon-gold-version/faqs/12550), the password is the sum of values derived from the trainer name, current amount of money, and trainer ID. You can get the maximum number of zeros at the start of the password by minimizing the value of each part of the sum. In particular, the minimum value is obtained by having a trainer name of "A" (128), no money (0), and a trainer ID of "00000" (0). In that case, the password will be "00128".

On the other hand the maximum value for the password is obtained if you have a trainer name that starts with `,,,,,` (1220), 65,535 money (255 + 255 = 510), and the trainer ID "65535" (255 + 255 = 510), for a total of 2240, resulting in the password "02240".

So, based on the information in that guide, every possible password is between "00128" and "02240".